# how to map hostnames to IP addresses on a Linux system

Tags: linux, hosts-file

I am migrating from windows to linux, and I am using ubuntu for my development now.

I installed apache and it works great; my problem isIi need to use a fully-qualified domain name to access my local webserver, ie `http://www.example.com/` should go to my local apache instance, rather than having to use  `http://localhost` or `http://127.0.0.1`.

In windows this can be achieved through the host file. But not sure about linux.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linux has a hosts file too, in `/etc/hosts`.  The format should be both familiar and easy to work out.

Comment: this doesn't work network-wide, though, does it? something like that would be best

Comment: It works only on the local machine. It is the job of a DNS server to make this mapping available to other computers.

Comment: @tekknolagi: It wouldn't necessarily be "best".  The question asks for the Linux equivalent of the Windows hosts file.  I answered that question.  When a question comes up asking "how do I provide name service for a network", I'll answer that one with something different.

Comment: sorry... and so i upvoted your answer :)